# Why does Python ctype c_char_p return different values on OSX vs. Windows?

Tags: python, windows, macos, ctypes

I'm learning more about Pythons ctypes module, and have noticed an oddity that I am not sure how to explain.

On Windows (Python 2.7.4), the following is returned:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> c_char_p("Hello World!")
c_char_p('Hello World!')
```

Whereas on OSX (Python 2.7.2), the following is returned:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> c_char_p("Hello World!")
c_char_p(4479401388)
```

Additionally on OSX, `c_char_p("Hello World!")` returns a different numerical value every time it is run.

Could someone please shed some light on why this may be occuring?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.4/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py#l243), `__repr__` will only show the contents of the string if

1. It is running on Windows; and
2. [`IsBadStringPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366714.aspx) returns `TRUE`.

They probably want to show a string representation if possible, since that's a rather useful thing to show, but not crash your program if it points somewhere unexpected. `IsBadStringPtr` only exists on Windows, necessitating the first check. Frankly, I'm surprised they'd use it, as it's clearly marked obsolete, and [for good reasons](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx).

Comment: You should add that the address will be constant if you reuse the same Python string, i.e. `s = b"Hello World"; c_char_p(s)`. That's why you only use a Python string directly with `const char *` (or equivalently `char const *`). That same rule applies to `c_wchar_p`.

Comment: Thanks, that source clearly shows it's written for Windows. After looking at the link eryksun provided it seems it's pointing to the memory address of the string (which was my initial guess), but it still hasn't been fixed.

Comment: @eliteparakeet: Heller's patch in [issue 1701409](http://bugs.python.org/issue1701409) doesn't fix the repr of `c_wchar_p`. It still segfaults if the pointer is bad on non-Windows platforms. Notice that for [`z_get`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/026ee0057e2d/Modules/_ctypes/cfield.c#l1367) and `Z_get` (line 1459) they moved the `IsBadStringPtr` calls into C.

Comment: @eliteparakeet: Also, as you can see in `Z_get`, on Windows a bad pointer causes the repr of `c_wchar_p` to raise a `ValueError` -- again, because the repr patch wasn't also applied to the `c_wchar_p` class.